# pyodbc.so is 64-bit instead of 32-bit

Tags: python, sql-server, kivy, pyodbc, buildozer

I have been being using and deploying some different packages into my kivy application without any trouble, until then, I hadn't to worry about the Android arch to build for and related to it, if my app will be 32 or 64 bits.

That changed when a module for working with a Microsoft SQL Server was implemented, I used pyodbc, for that reason I followed this tutorial: [Microsoft ODBC driver for SQL Server tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15), obtaining as result the installation of this driver: 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server'.

Later, I added [FreeTDS](http://www.freetds.org/) driver following the documentation and modifying the **odbcinst.ini** with these lines.

```
[FreeTDS] 
Description = v0.91 with protocol v7.2 
Driver = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libtdsodbc.so
```

And created a DSN in **obdc.ini** to call it later in code:

```
[dbserverdsn]
Driver = FreeTDS
Server = <Server IP>
Port = 1433
TDS_Version = 7.3
Database = <DB name>
```

Here how the connection is created:

```
self._db_connection = pyodbc.connect('DSN=dbserverdsn;'
                                     'UID=Arn_Rojas;'
                                     'PWD=password_here')
```

Everything worked fine in my LinuxLite machine with both drivers but when I tried to deploy it in android this error appears:

```
ImportError: dlopen failed: "/data/data/org.test.myapp/files/app/_python_bundle/site-packages/pyodbc.so" is 64-bit instead of 32-bit
```

I tried changing this in the buildozer.spec file:

```
android.arch = armeabi-v7a
# TO
android.arch = arm64-v8a
```

But it didn't work.

I also tried to find a way to install a 32 bits pyodbc driver but was not possible for me, so here I am, open to your suggestions and advices, tell me if you need more information.

Comment: Just to be clear, are you talking about the .so file for pyodbc itself (e.g., something like "pyodbc.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so") or the .so file(s) for the ODBC *drivers* (e.g., "libmsodbcsql-17.5.so.2.1" or "libtdsodbc.so") that you want to use? In any case, if you have a 32-bit box you'll probably need to build the components you need in that environment.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I think that I have to do, build the components in a 32-bit environment, however I have not the minor idea how to do that, my knowledge is limited to python but I'll try to follow the [documentation](https://python-for-android.readthedocs.io/en/latest/recipes/) and go on